# How do I calculate the following sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to calculate the sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n)(2n-1)}$$

I tried to write it as follows:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\left (\frac{2}{2n-1}  -    \frac{1}{n} \right) $$

However I did not deduce anything. I would appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: Hint:Do you know the sum of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$ ?

Comment: Writing $\frac1n=\frac2{2n}$ combine even and old terms $$2\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac1{4m-3}-\frac1{4m-2}-\frac1{4m-1}+\frac1{4m}\right)$$

Comment: Recall the Taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$ and $\arctan(x)$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How does that help? It's better to keep separated the series of $\pi/2$ and $\log 2$ that mixing them like that.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\left (\frac{2}{2n-1}  -    \frac{1}{n} \right) =2\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\left (\frac{1}{2n-1}  \right) -\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\left ( \frac{1}{n} \right) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use double integral to handle this series. Let
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n)(2n-1)}x^{2n}. $$
Then
$$f''(x)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n-2}=\frac{2}{1+x^2} $$
and hence
$$ f(1)=2\int_0^1\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+t^2}dtdx=2\int_0^1\int_t^1\frac{1}{1+t^2}dxdt=2\int_0^1\frac{1-t}{1+t^2}dt=\frac12(\pi-2\ln2). $$